# Wrong use of CDN (libphonenumber-js) or CDN not working?

Tags: javascript, cdn, libphonenumber

I am trying to use the library libphonenumber-js.

```
<body>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/libphonenumber-js@1.9.9/bundle/libphonenumber-min.js"></script>

    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

In my main.js I tried to write a simple code which is from the docs of libphonenumber-js:

```
    const phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumber('+12133734253');
```

However I get this error. Same thing with other functions from the docs.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: parsePhoneNumber is not defined
```

In my network tabs I can see that the min.js file is being downloaded. But its functions are not usable for some reason. I tried making a min.js file and using it as well but with not luck.

I also tried many different CDN services which also host this library.

Comment: https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js/#cdn

Here it says you can use a CDN. I don't understand why it would be an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone wondering:

I found out in the issues page of the repo that you have to use **window.libphonenumber** or just **libphonenumber** in front of the function. So

```
window.libphonenumber.parsePhoneNumberFromString(
      '(213) 373-42-53 ext. 1234',
      'US'
    );
```

Also in my example turns out that the correct function was **parsePhoneNumberFromString**

Answer (score 0):

> This fixed it for me, But since it still returns 3
> digits, which causes the field to change, triggering the event again
> and making it auto-format right back into what it was.

```
if (value.includes('(') && !value.includes(')')) {
      const tempValue = value.replace('(', '');
      return tempValue.slice(0, tempValue.length - 1);
}
```